# How to use NFC tags to trigger profiles and tasks in Tasker?

Tags: tasker, 4.3-jelly-bean, nfc

I am planning to get some NFC tags which I want to use to control some profiles in Tasker. Where in Tasked can I choose NFC tag as my trigger? If that does not exist, how can I turn tasks on and off for free using NFC tags? Any plugins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether *Tasker* can meanwhile handle that itself, but it's at least doable with the right plugin. There's e.g. [Locale NFC Plugin](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Locale-NFC-Plugin/se.badaccess.locale.nfc) which could fill this gap. Alternatives exist as well, like a modified version of [AnyTag](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2122019), which is used e.g. in [this tutorial](http://www.nfcbrief.com/2013/07/how-to-automatically-unlock-and-lock.html).

For more examples, tutorials, and possibilities, I recommend a GoogleFu, ahem, [search for "tasker nfc"](https://www.google.com/search?q=tasker+nfc&ie=UTF-8&hl=en), which brings up a lot of tuts and even Youtube videos explaining different magical things to achieve this way.

Comment: Yes! Locale NFC Plugin allows me to create a link directly to tasker, this means that it can carry out a task for me. Also it does not require direct writing to the tag which means I can use my Oyster card.

Answer (score 4):

[Trigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher) can, among other things, run Tasker tasks. In any case, it's probably worth while to check out this app if you plan on experimenting with NFC tags.